# Tshark -T output as json or ek

Tags: json, tshark

I am trying to use tshark with -T ek or json. I can many examples of -T ek or -T json but the only options I have when executing the CLI is It must be "ps", "text", "pdml", "psml" or "fields".

Has -T ek/json been discontinued?

Thanks for any guidance

Comment: The manual clarifies usage of -T pretty well, you can use either ek or json, but it does not appear that "ek/json" has ever been a valid option. Perhaps "jsonraw" would work for your use case? Scroll down to that flag here to see their explanation and examples: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html

Answer (score 0):

it might be due to the Tshark version you're using. I encountered this error when running -T json on CentOS 7 where my Tshark version is 1.10.14 (Git Rev Unknown from Unknown).

I was able to fix it by installing the latest tshark and export the desired JSON output based on the instructions provided in this link: https://linuxtut.com/en/972b9c5726deb7469196/